# Getting and uploading an output file from Python program in Ubuntu

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I have a Python file uploaded to an Ubuntu server that produces a .txt file. My questions are pretty straightforward but I cannot easily find an answer:

1. How do I automate the job so that it runs every day at the same time?
2. How do I get the outputted txt file and upload it into some shared repository, like GitHub, every day automatically?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What protocol is used to upload the file? FTP?

Comment: Running a job daily is done with `cron`.  Each user has its own cron table for running jobs periodically.  The command `crontab -e` will edit your cron table, but be sure you understand the format.  Like many old school Unix commands, the format is quite terse.

Comment: Storing your file in git is just a matter of adding `git add datafile.txt` / `git commit -m "daily update"` to the shell script you run from `cron`.

Comment: @TimRoberts any tips on writing a Python shell script for cron? Preferably with documentation for running and handling a .py file that produces output.

Comment: You need to read about cron.  Cron can run any command.  You'll probably want to run a bash script that starts your Python script, and then does the git commands.  https://ostechnix.com/a-beginners-guide-to-cron-jobs/